# Where to add @SdkConstant?

Tags: android, android-intent, sdk, intentfilter

Evening all, I have an android device with an SOS button on it (hardware) I am trying to set it up so that it calls up a test application I have created purely as a proof of concept.

This is the information I have been provided by the manufacturer

```
// Add for SOS/PTT Key Start
@SdkConstant(SdkConstantType.BROADCAST_INTENT_ACTION)
public static final String ACTION_EXT_PTTDOWN = "com.TMZP.Main.PTTDown";      

@SdkConstant(SdkConstantType.BROADCAST_INTENT_ACTION)
public static final String ACTION_EXT_PTTUP = "com.TMZP.Main.PTTUp";  

@SdkConstant(SdkConstantType.BROADCAST_INTENT_ACTION)
public static final String ACTION_EXT_SOSDOWN = "com.TMZP.Main.SOSDown";

@SdkConstant(SdkConstantType.BROADCAST_INTENT_ACTION)
public static final String ACTION_EXT_SOSUP = "com.TMZP.Main.SOSUp";
// Add for SOS/PTT Key End


Please NOTE:
Both the PTT up and PTT down intent are useful.

int ACTION_DOWN getAction() value: the key has been pressed down.

int ACTION_UP getAction() value: the key has been released.
```

The problem is, I don't know what to do with the @SdkConstant, I've never seen it before and cant seem to find any explanation.

Currently I have simply added the following intent filter to my test activity, however pressing the hardware button produces no result.

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.TMZP.Main.SOSDown"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Any insight into where I add the @SdkContant would be really helpful (or simply pointing me towards some reading material.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you building your own copy of the Android OS? Or are you trying to write an app using the Android SDK?

Comment: I'm going to write it with the Android SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@SdkConstant`, AFAIK, is from the Android OS source code itself, or things built into a revised version of that OS.

For your purposes, just comment them out.

> Currently I have simply added the following intent filter to my test activity, however pressing the hardware button produces no result.

That is because, based on the `@SdkConstant` lines, those are used for broadcasts, not starting activities. Try implementing a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens for them.

Comment: Thanks for the help ... I'll have a crack at a BroadcastReveiver now ... can I ask what you mean when you say "For your purposes, just comment them out" ?

Comment: @user2014175: Ummm... I mean "just comment them out". `//` is the Java single-line comment syntax -- just add `//` in front of the lines. What they did is copy a bunch of lines out of their Android OS revision and give them to you, ignoring that `@SdkConstant` is not relevant for apps. You could delete the `@SdkConstant` lines entirely, but since they mention that the actions are meant for broadcasts, that's a useful bit of documentation that makes them worth holding onto as comments.

Comment: Oh, they send them in a pdf :-) Thanks.

Comment: Perfect, broadcastReceiver worked, thanks very much.